# RiotJS not mounting tags

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I downloaded the Todo demo from Github: https://github.com/muut/riotjs/tree/master/demo

But when I drag index.html into the browser I don't see anything, just  tags.

I installed riot, only this dependency failed: `npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.5`

But it says optional. What could be the cause?

Answer (score 4):

[In-browser compilation](https://muut.com/riotjs/compiler.html#in-browser-compilation) needs Ajax access to your tag file. But modern browsers don't allow such local file accesses. We have two options to run the Todo demo.

- Run the local server like [ss](http://superstatic.org/), and open `index.html`
- Just open `pre-compiled.html` locally